# How to prove the method we cope with when $Y_p$ and $Y_h$ is not linear independent in ordinary differential equation is useful?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving the particular solution Y of a second order constant coefficient ODE $y''+ ay'+ by = ce^{mx}$ by the method of undetermined coefficients, if $Y_p$ has the same form as the homogeneous solution $Y_h$ of the ODE, how to show that we can multiply $X^{n}$ into $Y_p$ for solving $Y_p$, where n is the least positive integer such that the repetition between $Y_h$ and $Y_p$ does not occur?

Answer (score 0):

Very quickly: If $m$ is a solution of the auxiliary equation
$$
\lambda^2+a\lambda+b=0
$$
then we let $z=e^{-mx}y$ and derive a corresponding second order ODE satisfied by $z$:
$$
z'' + \underbrace{(2m+a)}_{\text{maybe zero?}} z' + \underbrace{(m^2+am+b)}_{=0} z = c
$$
So integrate once (or twice if $2m+a=0$).  The RHS corresponding becomes $cx$ (which you can read off $z_p=\frac{cx}{2m+a}$) or $z=\frac12 cx^2+Ax+B$ (which is really the same as $cx^2$ as far as the rationale for the this method goes), justifying the multiplication by $x^n$.  Similarly for higher order constant-coefficient linear ODE.

Comment: Yeah, my initial thought is the same as yours. However, if the case is that the characteristic equation of $″+′+=^{}$ has two distinct roots, then 2m+a is not equal to zero, which is hard for me to move on.